# create a unique tracking code

Tags: php, codeigniter, function, unique

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how is create a unique tracking code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884912/how-is-create-a-unique-tracking-code)

With this function i can create a unique tracking code?
What is your suggestion?

```
<?php echo strtotime("now");?>
```

The number of characters not more than 10.
Please call example powerful

Comment: Why not use the database auto increment id value mixed in with `CUST_` or such

Answer (score 4):

What about the [**`uniqid()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function ?

> Gets a prefixed unique identifier based on the current time in
>   microseconds.

With this functions, chances are far better for you to get a unique code than just using a data like you did in your question.

Also, you might want to take a look at what a [**GUID**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) is.

Answer (score 0):

If two users visit at exactly the same time, then they would have the same tracking code. I recommend using the Unix epoch as a seed for the `mt_rand()` function.

```
//mt_srand(time()); Don't seed mt_rand
echo mt_rand();
```

You could also use it (or only a section of it, say the milliseconds) as a prefix or suffix to the random number. But that would pretty much emulate what `uniquid()` does.

Apparently seeding is bad and boring (see @Gumbo). So don't do it.

Comment: `mt_rand` used to generate the same numbers when initialized with the same seed value until 5.2.1 (see [bug report #40724](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40724)). Besides that, `time` is pretty predictable.

Comment: @Gumbo: What is your suggestion?

Comment: @Julia Roberts: Don’t use something that so predictable like `time`. Generally, there is no need to seed the pseudo-random number generator  at all as that is already done automatically.

Comment: @Gumbo Nice catch. I've updated my code so that's it's practically impossible to be collisions between users. At least, it seems practically impossible.

Comment: @Julia Roberts Example is powerful? Sorry, what are you looking for?

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: Now this is really absurd. Neither the user agent ID (if even present) nor the IP address nor the combination of both are unique. Just think of a company or university network that filters the user agent ID. And even if they were unique, applying a non-bijective function on it might violate their uniqness. What’s wrong with using proven solutions like `uniqid`? One of the fundamental rules in cryptography is: Don’t try to implement your own crypto system.

Comment: @Gumbo Of course it's absurd! And nothing is wrong with using something bland like `uniqid()`! How about I remove the seed? Will that make you happier? :)

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: I would be happier if you would remove your `reallyUnique` proposal.

Comment: @Gumbo Your and my ideas of fun really differ, don't they!

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: I didn’t see any hint that it was just a joke. And there might be some people that actually would use your hoax proposal someday.

Comment: @Gumbo I meant you were taking things awful seriously. But no matter. We are human-we differ. That's what makes things interesting.

Comment: @Julia Roberts sorry for polluting your question page with our conversation. Do you mind clarifying what "Please call example powerful" meant?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the purpose of the your website...

In general, I would also add the user IP. so if two people are buying at the same time, you won't have an overlap.

Comment: how is it? Please explain and give example?