# how is create a unique tracking code

Tags: php, jquery, function, codeigniter

how can create a unique tracking code?
What is your suggestion?

The number of characters not more than 10 and use only of number .
 Please call example powerful...

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to allow for a few more characters, and let your number be a hex number, the [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function will be useful to you

Answer (score 1):

How about using time();?? It will give exactly 10digits and will be unique forever with a difference of microseconds:)

Answer (score 0):

```
$random = "";
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
  $random .= mt_rand(0, 9);
```

However if you want something more powerful you should consider using characters as well:

```
$random = substr(base64_encode(sha1(mt_rand())), 0, 10);
```

Comment: mt_rand used to generate the same numbers when initialized with the same seed value until 5.2.1 (see bug report #40724:https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40724). Besides that, time is pretty predictable. i want only number?The number of characters not more than 10 and use only of number

Answer (score 0):

Because of maximum random number limits, you might use something like this:

```
$number = mt_rand(10000,99999).mt_rand(10000,99999);
```

Or use `for` loop as @JK posted.
Then, you might check uniquiness of the number, and, if not unique, generate new...

Comment: mt_rand used to generate the same numbers when initialized with the same seed value until 5.2.1 (see bug report #40724:https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40724). Besides that, time is pretty predictable. i want only number?The number of characters not more than 10 and use only of number

Comment: As you see, it is a _Documentation problem_. And, you can see on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php that **The random number generator is seeded automatically.** in PHP 4.2.0 or higher. Also, you cannot generate absolute random number. It is pseudo-random in all cases. And, of course, mt_rand() uses "Mersenne Twister"-based algorithm, not time-based.