# unique number with function uniqid()

Tags: php, codeigniter, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how is create a unique tracking code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884912/how-is-create-a-unique-tracking-code)

how can create a unique tracking code with function **uniqid()** for insert in **database**?
What is your suggestion?

The number of characters not more than **10** and use only of **number** .
Please call **example powerful**...
With respect

Answer (score 2):

Use the database mechanism to create the id value. Which database are you using?

uniqid() generates a random value that can be eventually doubled. That is a bad solution.

Using time-based functions can duplicate code in concurrent applications.

Finally, you should create a table of identifiers in your database, generate an incremental value each time it is requested.